# Ignore Warning prior to upgrade?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, upgrade

Below is a warning that I got when I attempted to upgrade my ubuntu from 12.04 to 12.10

[image: Warning during an attempt to upgrade to 12.10]

I wish to upgrade because currently my screen brightness issue isn't resolved and I strongly feel it's due to the absence of a graphics driver (like Intel CedarView, which appears to be a driver meant only for the 32-bit version). The easy way out would be to upgrade but I get a warning as seen above.

**My Question:**

Would it be safe for me to go ahead with the upgrade or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your graphics card has a problem with Unity in Ubuntu 12.10.

You have a few options:

1. I think the best option boot 12.10 on a live USB and test your hardware. If it works well, upgrade.
2. If unity is slow you might need to consider an alternate desktop such as k/x/lubuntu. Again testing before you upgrade is the way to go.

I also advise you make backups before you upgrade in case you do have a problem.